# Azure devops Create custom tags

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, tags, azure-pipelines

I need to create a custom tag in Azure Devops pipeline. When the pipeline gets success, then the **Tag format** (Inside get sources in pipeline) from **$(build.buildNumber)** must be changed to a version mentioned in a file (a.txt) automatically.

As far, my version is read through my powershell script and when a build is success, then it shows my version from the txt file, and we need that to be pushed to Repos->Tags menu.

How can I achieve this using powershell or Rest API ? Any inputs would be helpful.

Comment: Not get your latest information, just want to check whether below answer is work for you? If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which can also benefit for others who has same puzzle with you. Also, feel free to leave comment below if still has any puzzle about it:-)

Comment: Need an update on which task group should we use to execute this script.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rest api you may use [tag extension as it is done here](https://damienbod.com/2020/04/20/add-git-tags-and-versioning-to-mark-deployments-in-azure-devops-pipelines/). You just need call it in this way

```yaml
 - stage: tag
  displayName: "Create git Tag"
  jobs:
  - job: tag
    steps:
    - task: git-tag-on-release-task@9
      displayName: "Add Tag to git"
      inputs:
        staticTagName: "TEST-$(Build.BuildNumber)"
```

And if you read value from file and assign it to variable using logging command you can use this variable on above task.

And if you want to also update build number you can use [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#build-commands):

```yaml
- powershell: Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(FullSemVer)"
  displayName: 'Update build number to $(FullSemVer)'
```

Comment: Could you please confirm which task group should we use to run this ?

Comment: This `updatebuildnumber` it doesn't matter. Build number is common for all stages. Or maybe you are asking about sth different?

Comment: Im asking about the task group to be used to run this script in Azure Devops pipeline. Could you please confirm ?

Comment: If you are asking if you can put this in task group, I say yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can run git commands directly in a powershell task. For below example:

Add below scripts in your poweshell script which reads the version from the txt file :

```
git tag  -a "CustomTag" -m "custom tag"
git push --tags
```

You can also use the extension tasks to add a tag. For example [Git Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ATP.ATP-GitTag&targetId=47097972-e633-4284-ad72-fe49f3c8dd5f) task.

First you need to add below script in your powershell script to set the version to a variable. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts) for more informaiton.

`echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CustomTag]version"`

Then Install the Git Tag task to your organization if it is not installed.

[image]

After the task is installed. Add this task to your pipeline after the task which executes your powershell script.

Set the tag field to refer to the variable (ie.`CustomTag`) you defined in your powershell script.

[image]

If you are using task groups in your pipeline. You can add this task after the task group which execute your powershell script.

If you want to use Rest Api. You can check out [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/989904/unable-to-create-annotated-tag-using-rest-api-post.html).